# Installing Ubuntu Natty on HP G7-1310US Problems :(

Tags: wubi, screen

I just purchased HP G7-1310US and tried to install Natty but ran into two problems.

1) I boot from liveCD and Ubuntu runs fine no video problem what so ever ( I had to close the lid and open and then disply would show up). After that I used install option and then screen becomes blank after a while. I read the other thread,( [Is It Possible to Install 11.10 on an HP Pavilion g7 Notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105651/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-on-an-hp-pavilion-g7-not) )setting nomodeset kernel option but it did not help to resolve black screen.
I also tried wubi installation method but the same result with the same problem.
I tried installing 12.04 from LiveCD as well as wubi but no go.

2) I tried to install from liveCD (non-wubi method) but I can not create extended partition as HD already has 4 primaray partitions: came with preinstalled Win7, HPRecovery, HP Tools and the other primary partiton. How can I install using this pre-existing 4 primary partition? Any suggestion.

---

Here is the display of the video card display that does not tell me anything as far as manufacturer goes:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:42 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu precise (development branch)
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-17-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 17 21:35:49 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. The following may help you:

#### Problem 1: Black Screen Issue

I was able to resolve the dim screen problem as detailed in my response to the question you linked:

[Is It Possible to Install 11.10 on an HP Pavilion g7 Notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105651)

Reread Part III on updating the Grub config file for help on making the fix "stick".

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/107924/46766) may also help (install fglrx), but I can't vouch for it myself.

#### Problem 2: 4-Partition Issue

Try this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10452335&postcount=2

I came across several posts addressing this issue as I was getting started with my install. I did a full fresh Ubuntu install so I don't have personal experience with this issue, but there should be plenty of help available online.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this is an error .... it happens the screen goes blank.. but actually it shows the lock screen... by defaukt the pointer is on the password entry just type in password and increase brightness... i too face this on my laptop bot on natty and oneric...

as for partitioning.... only upto 4 primary/logical partitions are allowed.....

you may have to re configure or re manage drives....

i can better help you of you provide a screenshot of gparted when running live or installed

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop. The screen goes black upon (re)boot b/c the brightness is reset to zero. <kbd>F3</kbd> (of <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>, depending how functional keys are configured in BIOS) keyboard key increase brightness.

When the screen goes black, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>) several times. Hope this helps.