# Why does Inkscape become unresponsive all of the sudden and how can I stop it from happening?

Tags: 11.10, inkscape

I've just started using Inkscape in Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm not sure what exactly triggers it, but at some point, the Inkscape viewport becomes unresponsive.

The viewport is still visible. I can still manipulate the window itself: move, resize, open menu items at top. The cursor switches style. But clicking on anything within the viewport has no effect.

I must close the file and restart in order to regain control.

Comment: try open it up via terminal and see what comes up in the terminal screen when it freezes

Comment: I'll try this next time I have a chance to play with it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/785701, and the problem seems to be Inkscape trying to access files that are currently unavailable to it (files that may be on network shares or external disks that are currently umounted or disconnected).

Mark Roth's answer on that launchpad page had a good suggestion to run "strace inkscape" from the terminal in order to see what happens when Inkscape freezes.  You may find that, rather than restarting the system, you can instead mount the disk with the file Inkscape is having trouble stat-ing then try starting up Inkscape again.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with Inkscape since I posted this. I went back to Fireworks on my VM. I'm pretty sure I was accessing files on my hard drive so I don't think that bug was the issue. Nevertheless, I appreciate the response and have selected this. I'll try running `strace inkscape` if it happens to me again.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me -- I forgot to unmount my NAS when I left the LAN and it caused inkscape to freeze after a split of second it is launched. I can tell this by quickly scroll after it's launched. The first few zooming in's are registered but then it's unresponsive. $umount -f -l /media/nas solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

What hardware do you have? Your computer may not have sufficient hardware to run such an advanced resource-intensive program.

Comment: New HP Pavilion. Probably not the issue. Unless it has something to do with the video card. (See http://askubuntu.com/questions/105651/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-on-an-hp-pavilion-g7-not)