# Installation problem ubuntu 12.04 with hp Pavilion dv4 3006tx laptop

Tags: unity, server, software-center, ubuntu-netbook

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop containing model is HP Pavilion dv4 3006 tx , it has 1GB Graphics card(
Video Graphics  AMD Radeon HD 6750M (1 GB DDR5) ). Installation process is taken by my laptop but there are problem when rebooting it . When i want to open ubuntu as my operating system it does't open , my laptop Display turn off .
more info about my pc configuration pls visit:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c02780984&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN#A1
Collapse this comment

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We need more details to help you with this issue. Does waiting help? do you get a prompt atleast? Are there any messages displayed on screen? Are you able to access recovery mode? Any info u provide can be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read and apply the advice in this link
[Is It Possible to Install 11.10 on an HP Pavilion g7 Notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105651/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-on-an-hp-pavilion-g7-not)

Since you have ATI/Radeon graphics card you'll prolly have to install the latest AMD drivers for that (advice given at the end of the thread link above). This next link is also helpful with a lot of info and screen shots

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Hope this helps. It helped me at least. 
Have a nice day